# Getting the target element name in data- attribute of the parent element through JQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two elements a source and target (sort of linked select).  I wish to get the target element's name in the source element's data- attribute. Is it possible?  The following code does not work.

```
<label>States</label>
  <select class='sparent' data-select-target='child'>
    <option value=''>Select State</option>
    <option value='AZ'>AZ</option>
    <option value='PA'>PA</option>
    <option value='TX'>TX</option>
  </select>
</label>
<div name='child' class='schild'>value</div>
```

JQuery Code :

```
$(".sparent").change(function(){
  var id = $(this).val();
  var target = $(this).data("select-target");
  $.get("includes/chainedselect.php", {id:id}, function(data){
     $(target).html(data);
  });
```

});

However, if I replace `$(target).html(data);` with `$("child").html(data);` it works.

Can anyone help me figure this out?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log(target)` (or `alert(target)`) above the problematic line? One reason that could prevent it from working is if you're using an older version of jQuery (HTML5 data- attributes are only available via `data()` in jQuery 1.4.3+).

Comment: I missed what @PaleshMondal said...see his answer below.

Comment: @Matt alert(target) gives the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your data attribute `data-select-target='child'` to this:

```
data-select-target='schild'
```

And `$(target).html(data);` to this:

```
$('.' + target).html(data);
```

and try again.

Comment: I have updated the question with the correct values (replace section).  I want to give the target element's name in the data attribute. Nope. It didn't work that way.

Comment: Then you have to use `$('div[name=' + target + ']').html(data);` instead of `$(target).html(data);`

Comment: Thanks Palash. It worked. But can I select the element by name without the element type (my element will be dynamic and can be anything like select or div or input)?

Comment: Yes sure. just use this `$('[name=' + target + ']')` and it will work for any tag with that name.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('div[name="'+target+'"]').html(data);
```

you are providing 'child' in the selector, but you missed to provide whether it is an 'id', 'class' or 'tag'.